# Vertical align texts in a div in my case

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertical align texts in my div.

I have something like

```
<div id='div'>
   <h1>test here</h1>
</div>

#div{
   float: left;
   padding: 10px;
   height: 180px;
   width: 130px;
   line-height: 180px;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

#div h1{
   height: 180px;
   line-height: 180px;
   vertical-align:middle;
   font:normal 0.9em proxima-reg;
}
```

I can't seem to vertical align the `h1` tag texts inside my `div`. My brain is fried now and I was hoping someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
#div {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 180px;
    width: 130px;
    line-height: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#div h1 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font:normal 0.9em proxima-reg;
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/sUzK9/

Your `#div` has well defined dimensions, which makes things easier.

I applied `display: inline-block` to the `h1` and removed any height/line-height values,
and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align` is meant more for table cells than it is for "non-inline" DIV elements.

Give your DIV a fixed width and height, and then try using `margin: auto 0px;` to vertically align it.

Or...

Give your DIV a top and bottom padding.

Either way, you'll need to text-align your text to center.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/zyB6C/):

```
#div{
   float: left;
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 10px;
   height: 180px;
   width: 130px;
   line-height: 180px;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: red;
}

#div h1{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   font:normal 0.9em proxima-reg;
    background-color: green;
}
```